# How I can add record to join table in create method?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, join

I have a problem with create method, when I trying to add record to join table.

```
def create
  @drink = Drink.new(drink_params)
  if @drink.save
    @drink.ingredients < ??? 
    redirect_to drink_path
  else
    render action: :new
  end
end
```

And at place ??? should be an array of choosen ingredients (by the user), but I don't know how I can do it. Any ideas?

Comment: `@drink.ingredients.create(...)`

Comment: Do you have `ingredient_params` in the same controller?

Comment: Yes, but I stil don't know what should be there. When I trying with 
if drink.save
  ingredient = Ingredient.find(params[:ingredient_id])
  drink.ingredients << ingredient 

I have an error 'Couldn't find Ingredient without an ID'